# Extra parameter in ajax request

Tags: jquery, rest

I am tying to make ajax request to server:

```
        $.ajax({

        url: 'http://localhost:8081/Service/service1?Type=Description',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: true,
        success: function() {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error!");
        }

    });
```

I have got an addititional parameter(**callback**) after this request sending:

```
GET service1?Type=Description&callback=jQuery17203365498781397116_1376058778118&_=1376058780059
```

In result server cannot handle this request:

```
404 Not Found
```

Is this problem with server implementation(does not handle callbacks in the right way) or I am doing something wrong while creating request?

Comment: Does your server support JSONP?

Comment: An extra parameter should not result in a 404 error. Can you request http://localhost:8081/Service/service1 in your browser and see if you still get a 404?

Comment: @AndrewK 
I can request 

    http://localhost:8081/Service/service1?Type=Description 

from my browser. It's only problem when making an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

The request seems to be fine (that's how I do a lot of my ajax requests as well).

The callback parameter is because you used datatype='jsonp'.

With jsonp, the server is expected to return something like

```
jQueryxxxxxxxxxxx("server response");
```

Where the jQueryxxxxx is the value of the "callback". Instead of making a direct ajax request, jQuery will load the page in a different way (that slips my mind right now) and will call that function in order to get content. This is a way to get around cross-domain issues.

Did you program the server-side implementation yourself? Perhaps you didn't set it up to handle a jsonp request?

Comment: Server-side implementation was not programed by me. I think server does not support JSONP, so this is the reason of that problem.